# Branch.io React Native single use invite link

Tags: react-native, branch.io

I am using Branch with the React Native SDK. I am trying to create a single use invite link scenario, i.e. one user has a link that they can share with one other person to allow that person to sign up to the app (or some other special privilege - similar to the original Monzo Golden Ticket). I can't find any way to do this with Branch/RN SDK out of the box. I just wanted to check if someone else is also doing something similar and if anyone has a solution that is all handled by Branch? I think what I am looking for is some way to expire a Branch link based on some event but I might be thinking about it all wrong. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that our team is following up on you via the ticket that you created for the same question. Please ask us via your ticket #00030056 if you have any further questions. Thanks!